# Putting comments in XML that is present in my C# XML comment blocks

Tags: c#, xml, doxygen, xml-comments, html-help-workshop

I am using a code example block in an XML comment as a simple way to give the user an idea of what the XML looks like.  This is a very rough solution and the user will eventually be provided with XML Schema for the xml string.  However, for now I'm going to just provide this information in my doxygen-based documentation.

For example, I've got something like this:

```
/// <example>
/// <code>
///   <!-- xml will go below this comment, but I can't display the comment! -->
/// </code>
/// </example>
```

When I look at my documentation, any line that has a comment just appears as a blank line.

I've tried escaping with `&lt;` and `&gt;`, and have also tried using `<CDATA[<!-- comment -->]]>`, without success.  The escape sequences are displayed as-is, and `CDATA` appears as-is, except that the character data is not shown.

What did I miss here?  :)

EDIT -- I need to clarify that this is not an issue with Intellisense rendering the information.  I would like the XML comments to display properly when rendered by Doxygen into a CHM (via HTML Help Workshop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where your XML source is appearing, is it in the documentation of a function or class? If so, try wrapping the XML in [`verbatim`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdverbatim) and `\endverbatim` tags. For the following example

```
/** A test class with some XML in the documentation.

 \verbatim
 <example>
 <code>
   <!-- xml will go below this comment, but I can't display the comment! -->
 </code>
 </example>
 \endverbatim
*/
class Test
    ...
```

I get the doxygen output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Chris!  The problem with your solution is that you're also displaying the <example> and <code> tags, where I just want the XML comment inside of the <code> tag.  That said, I can use your solution if I just use `\verbatim` as a substitute for the <code> tag!  Works well enough for me!

Comment: Great. You can also use [`\verbinclude`](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/commands.html#cmdverbinclude) or `\htmlinclude` if you want to include XML from other files, i.e. if you want to have example XML files in a sub directory, rather than embedded in your source code.

Comment: Oh that's even better.  :)  Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

When you tried escaping with `&lt;` and `&gt;`, did you use this syntax?

```
/// <example>
/// <code>
///   &lt;!-- xml will go below this comment, but I can't display the comment! --&gt;
/// </code>
/// </example>
```

It works in IntelliSense, and I don’t see any reason why it shouldn’t work elsewhere.

[image: IntelliSense screenshot]

**Edit**: Could you please try the following version?

```
/// <example>
/// <pre lang='xml'> 
///   &lt;!-- xml will go below this comment, but I can't display the comment! --&gt;
/// </pre> 
/// </example>
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did.  Perhaps my issue here is my assumption that Doxygen / HTML Help will render the comments properly!  Thanks for pointing that out.